# React Victory giving error Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to `VictoryLabel`, expected `array`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes, victory-charts

I'm using Victory chart with React, and I'm VERY confused with what's happening. I'm receiving the following error:

```
Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to `VictoryLabel`, expected `array`
```

What I have is very simple like this:

```
public render() {
  return (
    <vic.VictoryChart>
      <vic.VictoryBar
        data={[
          { x: 0, y: 100 },
          { x: 1, y: 150 },
          { x: 2, y: 200 },
          { x: 3, y: 50 },
          { x: 4, y: 500 },
        ]}
        labelComponent={
          <vic.VictoryLabel text={d => d.y} />
        }
      />
    </vic.VictoryChart>
  );
}
```

Can someone PLEASE give me an idea of the problem here? I have no idea why I'm getting the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Victory docs say:

> The labelComponent prop takes a component instance which will be used to render labels for the component

You still need to define the labels separately using the `labels` prop of `VictoryBar`. The purpose of `labelComponent` is to further customize things like positioning or add tooltip labels.

An example from the docs:

```
<VictoryBar
  data={sampleData}
  labels={(d) => d.y}
  style={{ labels: { fill: "white" } }}
  labelComponent={<VictoryLabel dy={30}/>}
/>
```

Here the `labelComponent` prop is used to move the y-axis of each label but we still have to define the label values with a separate prop. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Caleb; adding the `labels` property seems to solve the issue. I'm still confused however, I was doing the same thing in another component, and it was working fine... Anyway, maybe you can also give me a clue about this: I'm trying to set `tickValues` for an axis, and now it's complaining that arrays or iterators should have `key` property set, but I'm not sure if this is really the issue, or I'm missing something else?